# Particular application runs fine from xcode. but crashes when opened from simulator

Tags: swift, xcode

running the app fresh from xcode works fine. but after exiting the application from simulator and trying to open it again shows the launchscreen then crashes.

I tried with a fresh project but found no issues. Only the current application I'm working with has this problem

Any suggestions to what could be the issue

EDIT: No errors or warnings shown in the console. Probably cause i'm closing the application and then trying to launch it manually from home screen

Xcode version: 12.5

Note: I'm using m1 macbook, so I have excluded arm64 architecture for debug (for iOS simulator SDK) to get my code to compile properly

Pods installed in the project:

SDWebImage

Dropdown

GoogleMaps

IQKeyboardManger

Comment: Please share more info about what kind of crash you are receiving, maybe a code snippet where the crash happening would be helpful for the SO community to help you.

Comment: That is the problem. there are no errors displayed in the console. The app works just fine when running from xcode. but on tapping app icon from simulator after swipe closing the app this issue pops up

Comment: is there any way to see any errors after closing the application. sorry im pretty rookie ios developer

Comment: It is recommended to add log collection SDK